# How to get object name when it contains DOTs, CURLY BRACES and HASHTAGs on JSONPath?

Tags: json, regex, jsonpath, zabbix

I have the following JSON structure, generated by Zabbix Discovery key, with the following data:

```
[{
    "{#SERVICE.NAME}": ".WindowsService1",
    "{#SERVICE.DISPLAYNAME}": ".WindowsService1 - Testing",
    "{#SERVICE.DESCRIPTION}": "Application Test 1 - Master",
    "{#SERVICE.STATE}": 0,
    "{#SERVICE.STATENAME}": "running",
    "{#SERVICE.PATH}": "E:\\App\\Test\\bin\\testingApp.exe",
    "{#SERVICE.USER}": "LocalSystem",
    "{#SERVICE.STARTUPTRIGGER}": 0,
    "{#SERVICE.STARTUP}": 1,
    "{#SERVICE.STARTUPNAME}": "automatic delayed"
},
{
    "{#SERVICE.NAME}": ".WindowsService2",
    "{#SERVICE.DISPLAYNAME}": ".WindowsService2 - Testing",
    "{#SERVICE.DESCRIPTION}": "Application Test 2 - Slave",
    "{#SERVICE.STATE}": 0,
    "{#SERVICE.STATENAME}": "running",
    "{#SERVICE.PATH}": "E:\\App\\Test\\bin\\testingApp.exe",
    "{#SERVICE.USER}": "LocalSystem",
    "{#SERVICE.STARTUPTRIGGER}": 0,
    "{#SERVICE.STARTUP}": 1,
    "{#SERVICE.STARTUPNAME}": "automatic delayed"
}]
```

So, what i want to do is: Use JSONPath to get ONLY the object that {#SERVICE.NAME} == WindowsService1...

The problem is, i am trying to create the JSONPath but it's giving me a couple of errors.
Here's what i tried, and what i discovered so far:

JSONPath:

```
$.[?(@.{#SERVICE.NAME} == '.WindowsService1')]
```

Error output:

> jsonPath: Unexpected token '{': _$_v.{#SERVICE.NAME} ==
> '.WindowsService1'

I also tried doing the following JSONPath, to match Regular Expression:

```
$.[?(@.{#SERVICE.NAME} =~ '^(.WindowsService1$)')]
```

It gave me the same error - So the problem is not after the == or =~ ...
What i discovered is, if i REMOVE the curly braces {}, the hashtag # and replace the dot . in "Service name" with _ (Underline), in JSONPath and in JSON data, it works, like this:

**Data without # {} . :**

```
 [{
        "SERVICE_NAME": ".WindowsService1",
[...]
```

**JSONPath following new data structure:**

```
$.[?(@.SERVICE_NAME == '.WindowsService1')]
```

But the real problem is, i need to maintain the original strucutre, with the curly braces, dots, and hashtags...

How can i escape those and stop seeing this error?
Thank you...

Comment: `['{#SERVICE_NAME}']` instead of `.{#SERVICE_NAME}` ?

Comment: Oh, thanks :) "     $.[?(@['{#SERVICE.NAME}'] == '.WindowsService1')]     " - It worked, mate. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to answer below, i'll mark as solved... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.[?(@['{#SERVICE.NAME}'] == '.WindowsService1')]